# CSS border at end of line on inline elements

Tags: html, css

The default behaviour of inline HTML elements with a border is, that at the the end and the beginning of a line at a linebreak, there is drawn no border. Like

```
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

See result at: http://jsfiddle.net/yuszuv/ft7waga3/1/

Is there any way to draw the "missing" borders, so that each line seems to be contained in a box?

Comment: Note nice but maybe you can make it word-break: break-all http://jsfiddle.net/ft7waga3/4/

Comment: The somewhat new CSS property `box-decoration-break: clone;` solves this for Firefox.

Comment: @jan Thanks, I didn't know that new property. I've updated my answer with a solution for all browsers, except IE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot make each line contained in a rectangle using `border` on a `display:inline` element.
But, a workaround that works is to use a `box-shadow` instead.

```
span {
    line-height: 32px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ft7waga3/8/)**

Below a screenshot from FireFox:

[image]

---

As jan said, a better approach is to use [box-decoration-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break)

According to [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxdecorationbreak), this should work for all latest browsers, except IE:

```
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

**[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ft7waga3/25/)**

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Works on my FF 27.0.1 running in OSX. Maybe you need to add the prefix `-moz-`, so use `-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black; box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;`

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Yes I know that. I guessed that maybe you had a really old FF. So, please define what you mean by "properly".

Comment: [This is what I see](http://s25.postimg.org/js2erbfdb/what.png) on Firefox v34.0.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py The OP asked `Is there any way to draw the "missing" borders, so that each line seems to be contained in a box?`. Is not what the screenshot that I just attached does? Maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Yes, I can reproduce your image, if I zoom out my page. Try to reset your zoom (View > Zoom > Reset)

Comment: Nope. That still doesn't solve the problem. I don't know, maybe it's because I'm on Linux. Anyway, Nice Solution! +1 :)